# Configure imagemin-jpeg-recompress using npm script

Tags: package.json, build-tools, npm-scripts

I realize this is probably obvious to someone more experienced so maybe you can point me in the right direction.

I’m using npm scripts to run `imagemin` with the plugin `jpeg-recompress`.  It’s working, I just want to configure the settings for `jpeg-recompress`.

There’s an API and examples on the Github page https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpeg-recompress
but I don’t have the experience to know where these snippets need to be used. Should they be appended to my `imagemin` line in my *package.json* file? Do I go into my `node_modules` and manipulate `jpeg-recompress`?

This is what the pertinent part of my *package.json* looks like:

```json
"scripts": { 
  "imagemin": "imagemin src/*.* --out-dir=compressed --plugin=jpeg-recompress"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "imagemin-cli": "^3.0.0",
  "imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^5.1.0"
}
```

(All the examples I find are using Gulp and Grunt – Not what I'm trying for.)

I appreciate any help you could give.

Thank you!!!